# Port forwarding woes

Tags: windows-7, port-forwarding, nas

I have two WD NAS drives on my network, one is a WD 3TB My Book Live used for media sharing and storage. The other is a 2TB WD My Cloud used for work. I need to be able to connect to both from remote locations outside the home. I can get port forwarding to work with both drives independently, but not simultaneously. Can port forwarding be set up to work with two network devices, or is it limited to just one? Is there an alternative hardware/software way to accomplish this goal?

Thanks,
Lou

Comment: What protocol (HTTP, FTP or others) are used to access the disks?

Comment: is there a web front you are trying to access?

Comment: Since this is tagged windows 7, is the router running Windows 7? Otherwise which router do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

No, two devices/services cannot answer on the same port, on the same IP address.  You'll need to use different outside ports for each device.

So for example, assuming that you are trying to HTTP to the two devices (port 80), you'd forward your public-facing port 80 to the private port 80 of Device1, and forward another public-facing port (say, 81) to port 80 of Device2.

Then to get to Device1 you'd use `http://<ip address>` and for Device2 you'd use `http://<ip address>:81`.

If your NAT router doesn't allow an outside port to be forwarded to a different inside port, then you'll need to change the answering port directly on Device2 to 81 (or whichever your chose) and then forward the public-facing port 81 to port 81 on Device2.